# Can't use column-count CSS property with iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, column-count

**SUMMARY**

I'm using `column-count` CSS property to achieve a layout design like pinterest. But because of `column-count` if I put an Youtube Embed `<iframe>`, this iframe is disappearing. Can you tell me why it's disappearing?

**DETAILS**

I follow [this example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) for my grid layout. It's working good. But when I put and Youtube video iframe instead if `<img>`, it's disappearing when it's start playing. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xny8yys2/) is an example from my code (I didn't put all styles so you won't confuse). As you can see it's disappearing when video starts playing. But when I remove `*-column-count` lines from css, it's working. But this time I'm losing *Pinterest style* .

Comment: You should try to avoid iframe.

Comment: @Fury, you are right but unfortunately I need to use it. Because I'm developing this theme for non-technical customers. So they just want to use it, because when they click to *Share* button on Youtube, it's giving `<iframe>` code. 

In last chance, I'll use another options but I want to know if I can do it with `<iframe>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xny8yys2/1/

Ok, This was pretty messy. Try making your code clean because it makes debugging way easier. The issue here was two-fold.

- `.blog-list-template-pin img` This should include the iframe element if you want to use iframes in the columns
- Additionally, you added an inline css background-image to one of the columns parent div.
- Lastly, I recommend using display css for column structuring in a pinterest style. Same result, more backwards compatibility.

```css
.blog-list-template-columns {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
.blog-list-template-pin {
  display: inline-block;
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);*/
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.blog-list-template-pin img,
.blog-list-template-pin iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
.blog-list-template-pin .blog-list-template-pin-detail {
  padding: 30px;
}
.blog-list-template-pin .heading {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.blog-list-template-pin .post-date {
  color: #f03236;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.blog-list-template-pin .post-excerpt {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #515151;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.blog-list-template-pin .author {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #b8b8b8;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
}
.blog-list-template-pin .read-more {
  margin-top: 30px
}
.blog-list-template-pin .read-more:hover {
  color: #f03236;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 35px">
  <div class="row blog-list-template-columns">
    <div class="blog-list-template-pin">
      <img src="img/pin2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="blog-list-template-pin-detail">
        class="heading">TITLE</h5>
        <span class="post-date">29 DECEMBER 2014</span>
        <span class="author" style="margin-top: 20px">POSTED BY AUTHOR</span>
        <a href="" class="button-full-white read-more">READ MORE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list-template-pin full-bg-pin">
      <iframe width="367" height="206" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YJVmu6yttiw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <div class="blog-list-template-pin-detail">
        <h5 class="heading">TITLE</h5>
        <span class="post-date">29 DECEMBER 2014</span>
        <span class="author" style="margin-top: 20px">POSTED BY AUTHOR</span>
        <a href="" class="button-full-white read-more">READ MORE</a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list-template-pin">
      <iframe width="367" height="206" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YJVmu6yttiw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <div class="blog-list-template-pin-detail">
        <h5 class="heading">TITLE</h5>
        <span class="post-date">29 DECEMBER 2014</span>
        <span class="author" style="margin-top: 20px">POSTED BY AUTHOR</span>
        <a href="" class="button-full-white read-more">READ MORE</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a bug with Chrome and CSS columns. It only works if the video shows on the first column.

CSS columns implementation is not really ready for production.

Adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to iframe CSS solved this issue for me.

Found out about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760360/chrome-and-soundcloud-embed-issue-with-css3-columns/27200299#27200299).